# ADT Bundle for Windows 7 64bit missing JRE folder and wont run - I've tried

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, javaw

So I downloaded the 64bit version of the ADT Bundle from developer.android.com and what not, but when I run eclipse (from this bundle - this is not trying to add the plug in to an existing IDE, this is just the bundle) it tells me im missing javaw.exe in a path for adt...\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe

I found my personal java installation on my computer and copied the files over, but now it's saying it's failing at running a .dll file.

Does anyone have any advice? perhaps even which JRE version does this bundle use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, now I feel bad for asking when the problem was so trivial, so let me explain :D

I run a 64bit system,
for some reason java read my browser as a 32bit (I did not know there was only one version of chrome - 32bit - at the time) so I got a 32 bit version of jre, so when I copied over the files to the x64 adt folder it failed, and that's why.

so all I did was download x64 jre from a third party site (cnet) and then did my copy process over.

Worked like a charm :D

If anyone is having this issue I hope this post will find you (or you, it) and it'll help.
To the community, sorry for asking the question and finally solving it with my last attempt at my own troubleshooting xD.

***[Summary of problem fix]***
-Download JRE for your right version of the OS
-copy over the JRE contents and add them into your Eclipse folder.

keep in mind, your jre folder may be named "Jre7u" or something, what you want to do is open that folder, select everything inside, go to your ADT folder, go into the eclipse folder, create your own folder named "jre" and then paste everything inside that folder.

should work like a charm :D

-ZenOokami

Comment: You can also download the correct JRE (even x64) here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html and install it directly to a newly created `\jre` folder.

Answer (score 3):

you can also add -vm into the ini once you have installed the correct version of the JRE. Also could not get it to work from Programs Files (x86)

### So add this to the top of the ini file

-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin